# Debugging OOo UNO-Python

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, uno

I'm trying read and parse a CSV file in LibreOffice Calc. I need to show text in order to debug my logic, and the first thing I found was [this](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PythonDialogBox). Annoyingly, it duplicates functionality that's built into OOo Basic. The first implementation tries to use a non-existent function; the second one works if I invoke it directly (using `TestMessageBox` from the Tools menu), but when I include it from my `pythonpath` directory I get an error:

> com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeExceptionError during invoking function main
>   in module
>   file:///C:/path/to/test.py
>   (: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'MessageBox'   C:\path\to\test.py:34
>   in function main() [msgbox.MessageBox(parentwin, message, 'Title')]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\pythonscript.py:870 in
>   function invoke() [ret = self.func( *args )] )

Why is there no attribute `MessageBox`?

I'm invoking it like this:

```
import msgbox

def main():
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    parentwin = doc.CurrentController.Frame.ContainerWindow

    message = "Message"
    msgbox.MessageBox(parentwin, message, 'Title')

    return
```

And here's pythonpath/msgbox.py:

```
import uno

from com.sun.star.awt.MessageBoxButtons import BUTTONS_OK, BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL, BUTTONS_YES_NO, BUTTONS_YES_NO_CANCEL, BUTTONS_RETRY_CANCEL, BUTTONS_ABORT_IGNORE_RETRY
from com.sun.star.awt.MessageBoxButtons import DEFAULT_BUTTON_OK, DEFAULT_BUTTON_CANCEL, DEFAULT_BUTTON_RETRY, DEFAULT_BUTTON_YES, DEFAULT_BUTTON_NO, DEFAULT_BUTTON_IGNORE

from com.sun.star.awt.MessageBoxType import MESSAGEBOX, INFOBOX, WARNINGBOX, ERRORBOX, QUERYBOX

def TestMessageBox():
  doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
  parentwin = doc.CurrentController.Frame.ContainerWindow

  s = "This a message"
  t = "Title of the box"
  res = MessageBox(parentwin, s, t, QUERYBOX, BUTTONS_YES_NO_CANCEL + DEFAULT_BUTTON_NO)

  s = res
  MessageBox(parentwin, s, t, "infobox")

# Show a message box with the UNO based toolkit
def MessageBox(ParentWin, MsgText, MsgTitle, MsgType=MESSAGEBOX, MsgButtons=BUTTONS_OK):
  ctx = uno.getComponentContext()
  sm = ctx.ServiceManager
  sv = sm.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.awt.Toolkit", ctx) 
  myBox = sv.createMessageBox(ParentWin, MsgType, MsgButtons, MsgTitle, MsgText)
  return myBox.execute()

g_exportedScripts = TestMessageBox,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name `msgbox` is already used in UNO.  See [msgbox.MsgBox](https://docs.libreoffice.org/scripting/html/msgbox_8py_source.html).  Choose a different name for your module instead, such as `mymsgbox.py`.  Even better, move it to a package (subdirectory) inside pythonpath, such as `mystuff.msgbox.MessageBox`.

As a matter of fact, I tried `msgbox.MsgBox` just now and it seemed like it could be useful:

```py
import msgbox

def main():
    message = "Message"
    myBox = msgbox.MsgBox(XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getComponentContext())
    myBox.addButton("oK")
    myBox.renderFromButtonSize()
    myBox.numberOflines = 2
    myBox.show(message,0,"Title")
```

Comment: Awesome, LibreOffice found and fixed the problem already. Thanks for the link!