# libreoffice - need working example of msgbox macro in python

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

My request is very simple.  I'm trying to learn python macro scripting for libreoffice (Version-7.3.7.2) calc.  I have some radio buttons, and I just want to have a message box pop up when one of the buttons is clicked.  I successfully attach macros to the button events, and the events call my macro functions, BUT-

I've tried about 8 examples found online but none of them function properly.  when I click I always get error message boxes related to the code, and never the box I expect to see.  The examples seem to be incomplete, obsolete or referencing something not found.

I suspect there's something improperly referencing (or not referencing) something in uno or
com.sun.star.awt

I'm using Python-3.10.6, LibreOffice-7.3

I'm hoping that someone can point me to a simple, complete python macro that works, with just some message text and an OK button

Thanks -

Comment: For me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354073/debugging-ooo-uno-python worked without problems, could you try that and explain the issues that you encounter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging OOo UNO-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354073/debugging-ooo-uno-python)

Comment: I looked that up and tried it, after slightly modifying to make sure uno and com.sun.star.awt items were imported, and attached it as a macro for the button event.  When I clicked the button, I did get the message box - at first I thought it didn't work because I didn't see it, but then realized the message box showed up on the other monitor!  I have a multi-monitor workstation so I'll have to watch out for that stuff.